# RxKotlin - Single.just() does not emit when subscribing TestSubscriber

Tags: kotlin, rx-kotlin

I thought this is how it works, seems like I'm missing something..

```
@Test
fun singleCompletes()
{
    val testSubscriber = TestSubscriber<Boolean>()

    Single.just(true)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
            .subscribe { testSubscriber }

    testSubscriber.assertNoErrors()
    testSubscriber.assertValue(true)
}
```

> java.lang.AssertionError: Number of items does not match. Provided: 1  Actual: 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your invocation of `subscribe` is incorrect.

It seems you meant

```
Single.just(true)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
    .subscribe(testSubscriber)
```

Which would invoke the `subscribe(Subscriber<? super T> subscriber)`.

Your code is invoking `subscribe(final Action1<? super T> onSuccess)`, which would explain what you see.